# std::string::npos value is not -1

Tags: c++, string

It's been said in this doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/
that std::string::npos is -1. But when I print out the value, it's not. Is this value architecture dependent?

My test is very simple

```
std::cout << std::string::npos << std::endl;
```

which outputs

```
4294967295
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading a documentation link carefully.

Comment: @juanchopanza, you are right. I didn't think it through about the last sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the link you've given:

> This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for this type.

Answer (score 1):

> This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is
>   an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable
>   value for this type.

they say `an unsigned integral type`

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard data member `npos` of standard class `std::basic_string` is declared the following way

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

On the other hand type name `size_type` corresponds to some **unsigned** integral type. So what you got is the internal representation of -1 interpreted as unsigned value. This means that the sign bit was considered as a value bit.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers trying outputting the result of `(size_t)-1`.  You can verify that this value is the same as `std::string::npos`.